# Json array stored in DB issue - why trailing slashes when encoding

Tags: php, json, forms, symfony, doctrine

Entity:

```
//...
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="json_array", nullable=true)
 */
protected $params = null;

function setParams($params)
{
    $this->params = $params; //json_encode($params);
}
```

And form type:

```
//...
        ->add('params', null, array(
            'required' => false,
        ))
```

So, nothing unusual. The code above works correctly. But when I change the line in the setParams method to "json_encode($params);" (see the PHP comment at the right), I'm getting trailing slashes in the DB (when I dump the var, it looks ok BEFORE storing to DB). And it's incorrect only in DB, and only when I try to encode it. Interestingly, it's sufficient to pass array directly to setParams, and Doctrine saves it correctly...

Can someone explain me why?

Comment: Instead of *describing* the "bad" data how about copy/pasting an example instead?

Comment: @Sammitch When you don't put only the code that relates directly to the issue, the point is blurred.

Comment: I agree with @Sammitch, I'd like to see an example of these trailing slashes as they occur in your database. I'm thinking that since you defined the column type as `json_array`, there's some double-encoding happening when you `json_encode()` the data yourself. But to confirm that, we'd need to see an example of the incorrect data.

Comment: I'll write an example afternoon (no time now). Hold on with your minus-one downvoting. :P

Answer (score 1):

**json_array** now **json** (Thanks Stephan Vierkant)

Is a doctrine type for storing php arrays/objects into the database as a serialized json.

You should set your parameters as array not as json and you should do not call json_encode($params) inside setParams or json_decode in the getter. Doctrine will do all the dirty job for you.

```
function setParams(array $params)
{
    $this->params = $params;
}
```

Why do you want to have it as an array in your entity and serialized in the database?

1. It is faster/easy to manipulate native php arrays than json
2. Some database engines allows you to search inside json fields
3. Easier to edit with your DB Management system than serialized php or xml

Comment: This type is deprecated since 2.6, you should use `json` instead. But +1 nevertheless.

Comment: Thx for point this out. However I use the latest 3.x (3.4) Symfony, and it ships with Doctrine dbal 2.5.13, where json is not available. I get: " Unknown column type "json" requested." Here's the link https://github.com/doctrine/dbal/blob/2.5/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Types/Type.php